# Create-react-app + TypeScript + CSS Modules: Auto-generating type definitions without ejecting from CRA

Tags: reactjs, typescript, webpack, create-react-app, css-modules

**Problem**

`create-react-app` v2+ supports TypeScript and CSS Modules out of the box... separately. The problem arises when you try to use the two together. [Facebook had an extensive discussion](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/5677) about this issue and ultimately closed it off on GitHub. So developers have to use hacks and other workarounds to get these two technologies to play nicely together alongside CRA.

**Existing workaround**:

You can manually create `ComponentName.module.css.d.ts` files with type definitions like this: `export const identifierName: string`. This allows you to take advantage of TypeScript's typing and VS Code's auto-complete when you go to import `ComponentName.module.css`. Unfortunately, this is extremely tedious.

**Solution (?)**:

The folks over at Dropbox created [`typed-css-modules-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/dropbox/typed-css-modules-webpack-plugin) to address this issue; it auto-genertes those `*.d.ts` files for you. They show how to install it with `yarn` or `npm` and then give this minimal code example:

```
const path = require('path');
const {TypedCssModulesPlugin} = require('typed-css-modules-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/index.ts',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: 'ts-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          // Use CSS Modules
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: true,
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  // Generate typing declarations for all CSS files under `src/` directory.
  plugins: [
    new TypedCssModulesPlugin({
      globPattern: 'src/**/*.css',
    }),
  ],
};
```

Unfortunately, it's not immediately clear how I can use this with `create-react-app`. I'm not very knowledgeable when it comes to Webpack, and I'm using `customize-cra` to avoid ejecting out of `create-react-app` so I can customize the Webpack configs for some things I need. For example, Ant Design lets you import components on demand by using `babel-plugin-import` as detailed here:

https://ant.design/docs/react/use-in-typescript#Use-babel-plugin-import

**Question**: How can I convert the above Webpack configuration code to a `customize-cra` equivalent so that I don't have to eject out of CRA?

Answer (score 33):

Okay, so I eventually did figure this out, and I wrote a blog post on the subject for anyone who runs into a similar issue:

https://aleksandrhovhannisyan.github.io/blog/dev/how-to-set-up-react-typescript-ant-design-less-css-modules-and-eslint/#3-create-react-app-css-modules-and-typescript-

The solution uses the [`typescript-plugin-css-modules`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-plugin-css-modules) plugin. Here are the relevant bits from my blog post:

`yarn add -D typescript-plugin-css-modules`

After it’s installed, add the plugin to your tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": [{ "name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules" }]
  }
}
```

Next, create a file named `global.d.ts` under your src directory. You don’t have to name it `global`, by the way; you can name the file whatever you want, as long as it has the `.d.ts` extension. Enter these contents:

```js
declare module '*.module.less' {
  const classes: { [key: string]: string };
  export default classes;
}
```

If you want to also use SASS or CSS, simply add more module declarations and change the .less extension.

We’re almost done! Per the plugin’s usage instructions, if you want intellisense to work in VS Code, you’ll need to force VS Code to use your workspace version of TypeScript instead of the globally installed version. Remember when we installed TypeScript via CRA at the very beginning? That’s our workspace version of TypeScript.

Here’s how to use the workspace version of TypeScript in VS Code:

1. Open any TypeScript file.
2. Click the version number on the blue status bar at the bottom of VS Code.
3. Select Use Workspace Version (3.7.3 as of this writing).

Here’s a screenshot to make that clearer:

[image]

Once you do that, VS Code will create a .vscode directory in your project for workspace settings.

At this point, you're all set to use CSS Modules with TypeScript.

Comment: thanks alex, your link is not working..
updated link https://www.aleksandrhovhannisyan.com/blog/dev/how-to-set-up-react-typescript-ant-design-less-css-modules-and-eslint/

Comment: this solution works. Question owner should tag this as an answer... Thanks Alex

Comment: @alexh you rlobg post is down

Comment: did I really need the following part ?
 {
  const classes: { [key: string]: string };
  export default classes;
}
without it , still work for me

Comment: Followed this and Gorr1995s tweak and still didn't work...

Answer (score 7):

#### UPDATE 2022

**Note:** If you're using react-scripts@2.1.x or higher [you don't need to use custom definitions if you are using typescript-plugin-css-modules](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript-plugin-css-modules#custom-definitions) like

```
declare module '*.module.less' {
  const classes: { [key: string]: string };
  export default classes;
}
```

> **Custom definitions**
>
> Note: Create React App users can skip this section if you're using react-scripts@2.1.x or higher.

Also you can add this VS code setting to you local JSON settings file:

```
{
  "typescript.tsdk": "node_modules/typescript/lib",
  "typescript.enablePromptUseWorkspaceTsdk": true
}
```

This will ensure that VS Code will use the project’s version of Typescript instead of the VS Code version and will prompt you to do so if you aren’t already.

Comment: The best answer in 2022! Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Well, everything is correct as said AlexH.
1 in tsconfig.ts.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "plugins": [{ "name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules" }]
  }
}
```

2 in global.d.ts

```
declare module '*.module.less' {
  const classes: { [key: string]: string };
  export default classes;
}
```

3. But Also in tsconfig you should write

```
 "include": [
    "global.d.ts",
     ...
  ]
```